# shake build: read filepath list from config file

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I have a config.cfg file where a the variable file_list is a list of relative path to files

```
file_list = file1 dir1/file2 ../dir2/file3
```

How do I read this variable in to get a `file_list::[FilePath]`?
Tried to follow the [Development.Shake.Config API Doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.18.3/docs/Development-Shake-Config.html) without success. I need something to achieve that

```
file_list <- getConfig "file_list"
let fl = ??? file_list
need fl
```

ps. I'am an Haskell beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `file_list` is `Maybe String`, and the type of `fl` needs to be `[FilePath]`, so the question becomes how to write a function to transform between the two. One option is:

```
let fl = words (fromMaybe "" file_list)
```

The `fromMaybe` function replaces `Nothing` with `""` - so you now have a `String`. The `words` function splits a string on the spaces, to produce `[String]`. In Haskell `FilePath` is a synonym for `String` so it all works out.

If instead you want to error out if the key is missing, you can do:

```
Just file_list <- getConfig "file_list"
let fl = words file_list
need fl
```

Now you are asserting and unwrapping the `Maybe` in `file_list`, so if it is `Nothing` you get a runtime crash, and if it is `Just` you get it without the `Just` wrapper, so can simply use `words`.